# How to build kivy with sublime text mac OSX

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, kivy

I want to be able to build kivy programs from sublimetext2 by pressing cmd+B

I have added a kivy build as

```
{
    "cmd": ["kivy", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)"

}
```

but each time the error is

```
Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'kivy', u'-u', u'/Python_code/Test.py']]
[dir:  /Python_code]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

What is that i am missing in making build setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your `kivy` executable is in one of the directories listed in the path shown in the error, it won't be executed. To fix this, go to the command line and type `which kivy`. It should return the full path to the `kivy` executable. Next, edit your `.sublime-build` file to include the full path.

For example, if `which kivy` returns `/usr/local/bin/kivy`, then your `.sublime-build` file should look like this:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/kivy", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)"
}
```

Comment: for cross platform, similarly do: http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/151744/Sublime-Text-cross-platform-build-config